# Line-through when checked over multiple td's using CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, line-through

Im trying to do a linethrough over a label + checkbox both in a separate td.

**In my example code I have created 2 tables:**
Currently only table 1 is doing a line-through when checkbox = checked. I guess this is working because both elements share a td. Is there a way to fix this so table 2 can line-through instead of table 1? Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<table id = "1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="oregano"  type="checkbox" class="checkedBox" />  
            <label for="oregano" class="checkedLabel">Oregano</label>  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id = "2">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="oregano"  type="checkbox" class="checkedBox" /></td>        
        <td><label for="oregano" class="checkedLabel">Oregano</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Stylesheet:**

```
.checkedBox:checked + .checkedLabel {
        text-decoration: line-through;
        color: blue
        }
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/gdmpz506/

Comment: No, this is impossible in pure CSS since since CSS can't select an element via a parent-element. There's little (obvious) reason to use a `<table>` though, if you were to use a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) to contain the (apparent) list of ingredients/provisions, then you could use the same CSS. Otherwise, with both enclosed in different elements, this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in table 1 because there the `input` and `label` elements are siblings, i.e. children of the same element. It is irrelevant that the parent happens to be a `td` element. You are correctly using the “next sibling” operator `+`. (Here I’m assuming that you really want just the label struck out.)

The same is not possible when the `input` and `label` elements are not siblings, as they cannot be if they are in different `td` elements. There are no CSS selectors at present to handle such cases. You would need JavaScript to make checking a checkbox strike out the corresponding label.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have a different syntax for each `table`.

If you put the `checkbox` and `label` in the same `td` in the second `table` it will work just fine. (*and of-course make the `id` unique so that the second label does not point to the first element..*)

```css
.checkedBox:checked + .checkedLabel {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="oregano-1" type="checkbox" class="checkedBox" />
            <label for="oregano-1" class="checkedLabel">Oregano</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="checktd">
            <input id="oregano-2" type="checkbox" class="checkedBox" />
            <label for="oregano-2" class="checkedLabel">Oregano 2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gdmpz506/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that is not exactly what i meant. I've edited my question a bit: I know it will work in table 1. I want the line-through to work in table 2 with seperate td's.

Comment: @frontcamp, i see. unfortunately the answer is no. In that structure you cannot do it with css alone. Css allows only for sibling or descendant targeting. It can not go upwards in the DOM. You will have to use javascript for that case..